# How do I select non-adjacent ranges in libreoffice calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'd like to perform an operation on a set of non adjacent ranges in LibreOffice calc.

I can type: `C4:GA4` into the "name" box in order to select a single range. Is there a way to select non adjacent ranges (eg. `C4:GA4,C15:GA15`), or am I stuck using the tedious and error-prone Ctrl-click and drag method?

**Edit**: To clarify, I want a way to SELECT these ranges. I'm not attempting to feed them into a formula. In this particular case, I want to select a set of ranges for use in building a chart. There are enough ranges that selecting each manually would be very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is to use another selection mode instead of the standard, then copy the contents to another place (choose an upper left cell) and perform the desired calculation.

My suggestion for your case.
In the calc window, at the bottom, in the middle of the window, there are two symbols, The one on the left is grey.  So, you select one of the cells at the extreme of the range (ex. `C4`).  Then, you can press the `adding selection`. Press `CTRL + SHIPT + RIGHT` cursor to move to the other end of the contiguous block of cells (you're now at `GA4`).

Copy the cells to another sheet and possibly transpose the selection so that you have the cells in one column.

Repeat it to the 15th row and paste (and transpose) it to the end of the last set pasted.  Name the extended set.

Now perform the calculation you need.

Comment: This doesn't scale well. If, for example, I needed to do that 50 times for very long rows...it would take forever. It is slightly less error prone than using the mouse, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, calc allows use of multiple non-adjacent ranges in formulae:

The basic example I tried was:

=SUM(B2:B3,D2:D3,F2:F3)

Where it successfully applied SUM calculating every range.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really what I'm after. I've modified my question so that it is (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: In LibreOffice Calc 7.1 that syntax is not accepted anyway. When clicking interactively it seems the proper separator is a semicolon (`;`) and not a comma (`,`).