# How to use a non-contiguous range for diagram?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, range, diagrams

(Similar to question [How do I select non-adjacent ranges in libreoffice calc?](https://superuser.com/q/550667/964771), but not identical)

I have a time-based series of data (date&time, value), and I have a diagram showing the data.
The diagram uses the option "first row as legend" (or similar spelling).

Now that the data grows over time, I wanted to start a new diagram for a new year.
So my legend (labels) would still be in row 1, but the data start maybe in row 15.

The idea was to select row 1 in addition to the block of data belonging to the current year.
Say the first year uses `$Tabelle1.$A$1:$A$14;$Tabelle1.$E$1:$F$14`, and when I use `$Tabelle1.$A$15:$A$99;$Tabelle1.$E$15:$F$99` for the next year, unchecking the option "first row as legend", the labels in the graph are like "column E" and "column F".

So I'd like to re-check the option, and use something like `$Tabelle1.$A$1;$A$15:$A$99;$Tabelle1.$E$1;$E$15:$F$99` for the data, but that syntax is rejected (while it seems to be allowed in formulas).

Any solutions for that?
I'm using LibreOffice 7.1 at the moment.

Comment: As there is no answer yet, either nobody knows, or nobody knows because it's not possible. Anyway I've filed an enhancement request for that feature at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145861

Answer (score 0):

In my attempt there were seemingly two mistakes:

1. It seems I have to repeat `Tabelle1.` for each range when the data is on a different sheet than the diagram.
2. When using columns `A`, `E`, and `F`, the first row of each must be included.

So the overall solution was: `$Tabelle1.$A$1;$Tabelle1.$A$15:$A$99;$Tabelle1.$E$1:$F$1;$Tabelle1.$E$15:$F$99`